# Teklynx LabelView 2019 Server Activation

Tags: excel, vba

**Preface:** My programming knowledge is Beginner/intermediate, I apologize for any misunderstanding. I will do my best to describe the issue below.

**Software:** LabelView 2019 Gold & Excel

**Problem:** Activating a Teklynx VBA Reference Library "LabelManager2" apart of the TK Labeling ActiveX 19.0 (Ippx2.tlb).

**Goal:** My goal is to use the primary ActiveX library available as a reference library outside of the program (in an excel macro). LabelView allows the use of this library within the program's "Visual Basic Scripting" section of properties, however for my purposes this will not be a great option.

**What I have done:**
Researching online I found an old programmer's guide for this software ([Link](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/455645/Teklynx-Discover-Activex.html?page=14#manual)). After adding the appropriate reference library I attempted to dim and set the library with the following code:

Test 1:

"""

```
Sub lblTest()

Dim MyApp As LabelManager2.Application
On Error Resume Next
Set MyApp = New LabelManager2.Application

MsgBox MyApp.Path

End Sub
```

"""

The error I receive:
Run-time error '-2146959355 (80080005)'... Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation.  Upon clicking "Help" it brings me to a Microsoft page "Automation error (error 440)".

Test 2:

"""

```
Sub lblTest()

Dim MyApp As LabelManager2.Application
'On Error Resume Next
Set MyApp = CreateObject("LabelManager2.Application")

MsgBox MyApp.Path

End Sub
```

"""

The error I receive: Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object.

I have also contacted their support for assistance, however, they do not have any information they are willing to release.

Perhaps the syntax has changed since 2000 (the manual's publication date). Has anyone been able to take advantage of the activeX library outside of LabelView?

I don't know what to make of these errors and hoped someone would be able to shed some light on the subject.

edit: Test 1 was the same as Test 2, this was my mistake when copying.

Comment: Did you set a reference to LableManager2 or perhaps Lppx2 in the VBE's Tools menu? I suggest you drop the `On Error Resume Next` because you want errors to show up. If you declare MyApp As Object VBA will try to find the DLL at runtime. If you set a reference to the DLL your code will run faster and you will have help from Intellisense. I suspect that VBA can't find the DLL, and that would mean that you don't find it listed in the Tools menu, either. It may be in an unexpected location. So, you can browse for it and add the reference. Then try again.

Comment: I hope I follow this correctly. I am terribly sorry I do not. I have gone through the reference library. The reference that has "LabelManager2" in it is called "Ippx2.tlb". I find it within the library, however, if it is checked (Activated) it is called "TK Labeling ActiveX 19.0", if it is unchecked its name is "TK Labeling ActiveX 6.0". Going to the folder directory for LabelView and manually adding the Ippx2.tlb does not fix the issue.

Comment: T be clear, I'm just guessing and trying to be helpful. I don't know. However, if you want to use this program in VBA you must get it listed among the referenced libraries under Tools > References. It's quite possible that "TK Labeling Active X 6.0" is the name of the DLL. Since you suspect it I consider it likely. There should be help about this in the very impressive manual you linked. But if you find TK Labelling listed, put a checkmark against it and try your code again.

Comment: You are correct in assuming there is help in the manual. It lists the steps, this is what my code was based on and the original steps I took before asking the question. I also searched the directory for any .dll that may be associated, but no luck. I appreciate the help, hope someone has worked with this program before.